# Neural network always outputs the average of target values no matter the input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a neural network made with Keras (python) with a numerical input and a text input converted to encoded integers. It consistently outputs **the same value no matter the input**. The reason I think it outputs average of the entire `Y-train` array, which consists of normalized values mostly between 0.4-0.6, is that my model's loss is decreasing during training to really small values like 0.02 though the output is always the same. Training accuracy always stays the same and model is able to accurately predict exactly one entry. I checked which value does it predict correctly every epoch and it is **always quite similar to average**. Also the output of a trained model is **almost identical to the average**.

Firstly I tried training the model with 3 different optimizers and 2 loss functions (**6** **models** in total), each model produced its own output, they were different, but in terms of 1 model it was again, **same no matter the input**. I was searching for a solution for a long time, and I found plenty of methods that should've helped.
I implemented `weight regularization and initialization`, `early stopping` and `dropout` (against overfitting), I `scaled all the inputs and outputs`, but still it didn't help. Then I found a question describing similar problem, and people were telling that the model was just **not complex enough** and that it was **increasing its biases and decreasing its weights** in the training phase, which sounded reasonable. I checked my model and actually my biases were something like **`0.05`** while weights were about **`1-e10`**. So I coded in `Zero bias initializers`, quite `strong regularizers for them`, changed `activation fucntions to LeakyReLU` (against dead neurons), made an `increased complexity model`, all which resulted in the code below. I tried training it several times while `tweaking learning rates from values like 0.003 to 1e-6` during each epoch and still output stays the same. Loss was higher during most of the training because of bias regularization I think, but the result was the same - **model with 0.02-0.03 loss which outputs the same average value of `Y_train` no matter the input**. Also, I consider my training data as good as it can be because the amount of time I spent searching for mistakes in it, improving preprocessing and quadruple-checking it all is *insane*.

Here is the code:

```
def regDense(a):
    return layers.Dense(a, activation=LeakyReLU(), kernel_initializer=initializers_v2.HeNormal(),
                       kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), bias_initializer=initializers_v2.Zeros(),
                       bias_regularizer=l1_l2(0.003, 0.02))


def regLSTM(a):
    return layers.LSTM(a, kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(0.0001, 0.0003),
                kernel_initializer=initializers_v2.GlorotNormal(),
                bias_initializer=initializers_v2.Zeros(),
                return_sequences=True,
                bias_regularizer=l1_l2(0.0002, 0.002))


num_inp = keras.Input(shape=(30, 3, 1), name='nums')
text_inp = keras.Input(shape=(30, 7, 3208), name='text')

embed = layers.Embedding(vocabsize, output_dim=152)(text_inp)
tlstm1 = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.TimeDistributed(regLSTM(256)))(embed)
tdrop1 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(tlstm1)
nlstm1 = layers.TimeDistributed(regLSTM(256))(num_inp)
ndrop1 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(nlstm1)


tlstm2 = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.TimeDistributed(regLSTM(256)))(tdrop1)
tdrop2 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(tlstm2)
nlstm2 = layers.TimeDistributed(regLSTM(256))(ndrop1)
ndrop2 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(nlstm2)


tlstm3 = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.TimeDistributed(regLSTM(256)))(tdrop2)
tdrop3 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(tlstm3)
ndense1 = regDense(213)(ndrop2)
ndrop3 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(ndense1)


tdense1 = regDense(200)(tdrop3)
tdrop4 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(tdense1)
ndense2 = regDense(170)(ndrop3)
ndrop4 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(ndense2)


tdense2 = regDense(144)(tdrop4)
tpool2 = layers.MaxPooling3D((1, 1, 401), padding='same')(tdense2)
trsp1 = layers.Reshape((30, 1152, 7))(tpool2)
tpool3 = layers.MaxPooling2D((1, 3), padding='same')(trsp1)
trsp2 = layers.Reshape((2688, 30))(tpool3)
tpool4 = layers.MaxPooling1D(7, padding='same')(trsp2)
trsp3 = layers.Reshape((30, 384))(tpool4)
tdrop5 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(trsp3)
ndense3 = regDense(128)(ndrop4)
nrsp = layers.Reshape((30, 384))(ndense3)
ndrop5 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(nrsp)


concat = layers.concatenate([tdrop5, ndrop5])
prc1 = regDense(384)(concat)
pdrop1 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(prc1)
prc2 = regDense(192)(pdrop1)
pdrop2 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(prc2)
prc3 = regDense(96)(pdrop2)
pdrop3 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(prc3)
prc4 = regDense(48)(pdrop3)
pdrop4 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(prc4)
prc5 = regDense(24)(pdrop4)
pdrop5 = layers.Dropout(0.3)(prc5)
prc6 = regDense(12)(pdrop5)
lastpool = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(prc6)
last = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0008),
                    kernel_initializer=initializers_v2.HeNormal(),
                    bias_initializer=initializers_v2.Zeros(),
                    bias_regularizer=l1_l2(0.003, 0.02),
                    name='output')(lastpool)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[num_inp, text_inp], outputs=last)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
    {"nums": X1_train, "text": X2_train},
    {"output": y_train}, validation_data=({'nums':X1_test, 'text':X2_test}, y_test),
    epochs=9, callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=1, restore_best_weights=True), callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(schedule=scheduler, verbose=1)],
    batch_size=1)
```

EDIT:
Just checked the weights and biases of a recently trained model.
Almost in all layers weights look like this:

```
-4.1277455e-33  1.9695687e-33  4.1031190e-23 ... -1.5578026e-20
  -8.8301270e-33 -1.5537877e-20
```

And biases look like this:

```
-4.0955161e-05  4.0955088e-05 -4.0955132e-05 -4.0955088e-05
 -4.0955088e-05 -4.0955132e-05 -4.0955132e-05 -4.0955088e-05
```

Comment: This model seems strange, e.g. time-distributing LSTM layers, which inherently already go over time... Also, if your model is underfitting, first step should be to remove regularization, such as dropout and weight penalties.

Comment: @xdurch0 Time-distributing is needed because I want LSTMs to treat text data one-by-one, but its dimensions are such that as far as I know there is no way to do this except for time-distributing. Also, as I mentioned in my question, model behaved the same way even without dropout and weight regularization.